# Prevent multiple ajax calls on enter press

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am using a php chat plugin. Problem with this chat plugin is it works great when message is send through button press but when its set to enter press it invokes too many ajax calls. Sometimes it sends single message and sometimes 4 5 messages are being sent . I have tried all the solutions like defining a variable to have a check on it but i am not sure what i am missing here is the snippet of function used for sending message

```
$("#text-messages-request").on("focus", "textarea.type-a-message-box", function() {
    var ID = $(this).attr("id");
    var URL = $.base_url + 'ajax/add_chat_ajax.php';

    $('div.message-btn-target').html('<a href="#" id="' + ID + '" class="btn btn-default btn-sm send-message"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></i> ' + $.sendButton + '</a>');
    //$('#type-a-message').remove();    

    user_is_typing(this, ID);

    $(this).on('blur', function() {
        stop_type_status();
    });

    // Input Handler
    if ($.enterIsSend == true) {
        var running = false;
        $(document).bind("keypress", function(e) {
            if (e.which == 13) {
                if (running === false) {
                    running = true;
                    send_message(ID, URL);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        $("a.send-message").on("click", function() {
            if (running === false) {
                running = true;
                send_message(ID, URL);
                $(".type-a-message-box").focus();
            }
        });
    } else {
        $("a.send-message").on("click", function() {
            send_message(ID, URL);
            $(".type-a-message-box").focus();
        });
    }
    return false;
});
```

Please help i am stuck on this for days .
There is this real time chat function which initiates when both users are online and it keeps calling itself after every 7 secs

```
setInterval("realtime_chat()", 7000);
function realtime_chat()
{   
last_msg_id = $(".msg-div").last().attr("id");

var ID = $("#text-messages").attr("rel");

var R_URL = $.base_url + 'ajax/refresh_unreadMessages_ajax.php';
var URL = $.base_url + 'ajax/chat_realtime_ajax.php';
var I_URL = $.base_url + 'ajax/chat_last_id.php';

var dataString = 'id='+encodeURIComponent(ID);


$.post(URL, dataString, function(html) {
    var html_response = $(html);
    var new_msg_id = html_response.attr("id");

    if(new_msg_id !== last_msg_id)
    {
        $("#text-messages").append(html);

    }

})


// deal with update counter and typing status
$('ul#messages-stack-list li').each(function() {
    cID = $(this).attr('id');
    cString = 'id='+cID;
    type_status(cID);
    update_unMsg_counter(R_URL, cString, cID, 'realtime');
});

title_unread_counter();

return false; }
```

Its just to append what if there is some new message stored in database.
and here is my html of textbox

```
<div id="type" class="collapse border-top">
<textarea type="text" class="form-control border-none" id="type-a-message-  box" placeholder="Write the message"></textarea>
</div>
```

function for getting textarea content is at top and the send message function is as follows

```
function send_message(ID, URL)
{
    var textarea = $('textarea.type-a-message-box').val();
    if ($.trim(textarea).length == 0) 
    {
        alert($.emptyBox);
    } else {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: URL,
            data: {id: ID, message: textarea},
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() { $('#loadingDiv').show(); },
            error: function() { $('#loadingDiv').hide(); $('#errorDiv').html('<p>'+$.ajaxError+'</p>'); },
            success: function(html) {
                $('#loadingDiv').hide();
                $("p.no-messages").remove();
                $("#text-messages-request").html(html);
                $("#text-messages").attr("rel", ID);
                stop_type_status();
                $(".type-a-message-box").focus();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Hope it will help in formulating the solution

Comment: I would do this on form submit. Message will send onSubmit . As we know onSubmit will call on enter.

Comment: problem is its just a text box not a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than *keypress* use **Keyup** event.

Comment: and how keyup is going to help?

Comment: if we hold the enter key then multiple times send message will be executed. keyup will execute only on when user releases the key. but in your case keyup is also not working. can you post the html elements and more of your js code?

Comment: Add a debug point to the send_message function and then check the call stack. Check if the initiator is keypress event. Release the debug point and then again check the call stack. You will get  the reason of multiple calls.

Comment: Hi thanks you for follow up . I have added that debug point its on keyup and it works fine as long as the debug point is there but once its removed , its behaving the same still couldn't get hold of the problem. its getting onto my nerves now

Comment: When 2nd time debug points hits by pressing f8 ( win chrome) check call stack for the again initiation of the call

Comment: can you have a look at it for me ? please if I provide you link and credentials

Comment: Okay sure.. but rather than providing me the credentials, send me the source, i'll send u the fix

Comment: Source files are too much if you can just have a look at it to know where the problem is   https://www.artimization.com/client-management/ the link of the site and username: rafia_mudasar@yahoo.com pw: flynn_reider1 go directly to chat tab and omer's chat will be your starting point . Its under development so ignore any styling fixes

Comment: I've checked the code. Problem is that you are binding the keyup event again n again on focus of textarea ("#text-messages-request"). If you've noticed that first time message goes once. but on focusing on again the textarea again keyup get binds and twice the event triggers. Number of bind increases as the number of times you focus on textarea.
Use 
`$(document).one("keyup" , function(e){
//rest of your code
}`

Also don't attach the keyup to document. rather than document attach it to textarea. thats good practice.

Comment: can you write it up ? as I have tried to use that one function as you suggested and i guess it doesnot work because there are many keyups after writing up texts then after first keyup it gets disabled or something

Comment: Okay i will write it

Comment: hey I did it. Thumbs up to you . I made two separate functions one for focus related functionality and other on keyup event. you have been great help

Comment: Glad it helped!